# Comparing installed and current versions

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to get installed versions and current versions from a log file and I have got the output by using the following commands:

```
$versions = Select-String -Path $path -Pattern "Comparing product versions" |
            % { $_.Line.Split() }

$installed = $versions[6]
$installed = echo "$installed".Trim(",")
$current   = $versions[7]
```

The problem is: I don't want hardcoding. Is there any method like regex to replace this and to get installed version and current version seperately.

This is what the relevant log line looks like:

```
ISS_LOG [14:45:36]: Comparing Product Versions - Installed[1.2.0.10], Current[1.2.0.10]
```

Trying the 1st solution, I get an error:
[image: Error - cannot index into null array]

Comment: What exactly do you refer to as "hardcoded"?

Comment: if i specify the position of string as 7 then that will be hardcoding .In some cases the position may differ so i won't get the correct output.

Comment: Sorry, but the crystal ball is at the cleaner's. Please provide sample input and explain what you want to extract from it. [Edit] your question to do so.

Comment: `ISS_LOG [14:45:36]: Comparing Product Versions - Installed[1.2.0.10], Current[1.2.0.10]` this a line in log file i want to get the output $installed=1.2.0.10 in one line and $current=1.2.0.10 in next line using regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regex strings `Installed\[(.*)\],` and `Current\[(.*)\]`, assuming the pattern is that you have installed/current followed by square brackets with the version number.

This returns groups with a full match (not what you want) and match for what's int he square brackets (what you want). [More regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/A27VCy/1)

**In Code:**

```
$myString = "ISS_LOG [14:45:36]: Comparing Product Versions - Installed[1.2.0.10], Current[1.2.0.10]"

$installedRegex = "Installed\[(.*)\],"
$currentRegex   = "Current\[(.*)\]"

$installedVersion = $([regex]::Matches($myString,$installedRegex)).Groups.value[1]
$CurrentVersion   = $([regex]::Matches($myString,$currentRegex)).Groups.value[1]
```

**Output**
[image: On PowerShell 5.1]

**Edit - PowerShell 2.0 version**

```
$installedVersion = $([regex]::Matches($myString,$installedRegex)).Groups[1].value
$CurrentVersion   = $([regex]::Matches($myString,$currentRegex)).Groups[1].value
```

Comment: am getting error after executing $installedVersion ,the error is cannot index into a null array

Comment: Working fine for me in PowerShell 5.1 - added output screenshot. 
Bear in mind this will only function correctly when the line has `Installed[ver],` and `Curent[ver]`... otherwise no matches will be found and the array will be null.
You can deal with this in a `try`/`catch` or using `if($myString -like ...` to only process strings you know will have these fields.

Comment: as per your screenshot i will accept your answer but my problem is not yet solved,i have attached the screenshort as an answer,i hope you will give me a solution.Anyhow thanks buddy

Comment: @SumithChalil Edit your question to post additional information, or post the link in a comment... I am curious why this isn't working!

Comment: i have updated the question with screenshot of the code error when i executed with the code which is worked for u

Comment: @SumithChalil Aaa, it's the PowerShell 2.0 engine. Please see edit; looks like it deals with groups differently.

Comment: Thanks buddy.So the version was giving the error.Now it is giving the output perfectly,Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @gmsOulman bro how to remove all the characters from a string and keep only integers in a column of an imported csv file